# How to include proto files from one project in another project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, grpc

I am not able to include protos present in Project A in a project B. The idea would be to have the protos with `GrpcServices="Server"` in project A and in project B, of tests, include the same protos but, now, as `GrpcServices="Client"`

`ProjectA/Protos/Profile.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";

package profile;
option csharp_namespace = "ProjectA.Protos";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service ProfileService {
  rpc Get(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (Profile);
}

message Profile {
  string profile_id = 1;
  string description = 2;
}
```

`ProjectA/Protos/User.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";

package user;
option csharp_namespace = "ProjectA.Protos";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
import "Protos/Profile.proto";

service UserService {
  rpc Get(google.protobuf.StringValue) returns (UserDetail);
}

message UserDetail {
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  repeated profile .Profile profiles = 7;
}
```

Project B .csproj (The test project)

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="..\ProjectA\Protos\*.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos">
    <Link>Protos\*.proto</Link>
  </Protobuf>
</ItemGroup>
```

With these settings I always end up having this error return

```
error : File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).
```

Comment: looks like you're setting `ProtoRoot="Protos"`, but you're trying to `import "Protos/Profile.proto"` (which means you're looking for "Protos/Protofile.proto" under the directory "Protos" - and "Protos/Protos/Protofile.proto" doesn't exist). Try using ProtoPath="..\ProjectA" instead?  You might need to experiment a bit.

Comment: Alternatively, a common pattern is for you to have one shared class library with all generated protobuf sources. All the other projects then just reference the shared class library.

Comment: ProtoRoot does exactly that role of indicating the root where the "imported" files would be. The problem is that the classes generated from proto files enter the global namespace of the application and therefore always end up in conflict between projects. This suggestion given is a great alternative. But, for me it was simpler to change the compilation settings of my proto file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bringing a return on the applied solution.

The problem that occurs when trying to do this import in the same solution is that each inclusion in a `.csproj` it will try to generate C# classes and these classes are generated with "global context" and this prevents the generation of "server" and "client" classes because they would have the same names.

The easiest solution was to add `Both` to the proto file's include configuration. Thus, the generated C# classes already contemplate the client and server side, so it is possible to use them both in project A (server) and in project B (client).

`<Protobuf Include="Protos\*.proto" GrpcServices="Both" />`

The solution presented by Jan Tattermusch, in the comments, would have a project C with only the protos files, would follow the same configuration and is also a great alternative.