# DotNet Core Create Proto message common library

Tags: .net-core, grpc, proto, protocol-buffers

The use case is pretty simple:
I have two projects (ProtoProvider & ProtoConsumer).
[image]

ProtoProvider has the proto file (to_import.proto) and the message I want to use on the ProtoConsumer.
[image]
ProtoConsumer has a referrence on ProtoProvider and attempts to use the ProvidedMessage in the imported.proto.
[image]
I cannot use the the message because I get "File not found." on the impoort and "ProvidedMessage is not defined" on the compiler for the imported.proto.

EDIT2>>>
To clarify I want to create a message like google's google.protobuf.Timestamp and distribute it to another project or projects without the other projects while having the project/projects (consumer) getting the message from the dll. The whole premise of the question is how to use the message defined in to_import.proto in another project through the dll (think of it as a common.grpc lib).

EDIT1>>>
The error messages I'm getting
[image]

Is there a solution that allows the importing of the proto files from a project reference?
I'm looking for something like google's solution for the well-known-types

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
```

source: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial#where-to-find-the-example-code.
(Copying the proto files or moving the files is not an elegant solution).

Below I'll provide the .csproj files

ProtoProvider:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="to_import.proto" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.27.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="to_import.proto" GrpcServices="None" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

ProtoConsumer:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\imported.proto" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.27.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ProtoProvider\ProtoProvider.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Edit>>3
Some context : The purpose of this question is to help me understand a clearer way to implement decimal once (as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/protobuf?view=aspnetcore-3.1#decimals)) and reuse them in each project.

Comment: I'm not getting your problem. Provider and Consumer can use the same ``proto`` file. You  declare your messages and compile to native code. The native code you import. I don't understand your search for a "well-known" type.

Comment: So while building you are not getting a File not found error? 
I'm updating the original post with the error messages

Comment: I'm not using C#, but I get it now. Have you checked your import syntax to make sure it is correct (package names, etc...)? Your csharp namespace doesn't include "common".

Comment: That's what I am interested in finding, how to correctly imported. 
I've tried many different combinations of package + protofile name, package + class name, namespace + protofile name and namespace + class name. All of them lead to a file not found error.

Comment: If the C# environment is anything at all like the Java environment, the ``csharp_namespace`` should be the prefix/path/directory of the fully qualified pathname, not ``ProtoConsumer``. Have you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64547422/how-to-include-proto-files-from-one-project-in-another-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, compiling `proto` files requires all files (including imports) to exist on disk.

The way this works for the well known types is that they are included in [`Grpc.Tools` nuget package](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/Grpc.Tools/Grpc.Tools.csproj#L59).

So its not possible to ship a class library that accomplishes what you want.

Discussion on a related [`grpc-dotnet` issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/183#issuecomment-525386586) suggests using a combination of:

- Building a nuget package containing your common proto and associated class library
- In the consuming code's package reference, use `GeneratePathProperty` to generate a variable holding the path to the nuget package content
- In the consuming code's `Protobuf Include`, use `AdditionalImportDirs` to include the common proto from the nuget package.